# How to allow only !@#$%^&* in a string using java

Tags: java, regex

I want to allow only above mentioned special characters.

I tried with this

```
private final Pattern hasSpecialChar = Pattern.compile("[!@#$%^&*]");
if (!hasSpecialChar.matcher(password).find()) {
    return "String allows only !@#$%^&* special characters";
}
```

but it is allowing other special characters also.

Can any body help me to create a proper regex.

Comment: Try `"^[\\p{Alnum}\\s!@#$%^&*]*$"`, maybe even like `return password.matches("[\\p{Alnum}\\s!@#$%^&*]*");`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
private final Pattern hasSpecialChar = Pattern.compile("[^A-Za-z0-9!@#$%^&*]+");
if (hasSpecialChar.matcher(password).find()) {
    return "String allows only !@#$%^&* special characters";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mabe below snippet will help you:

```
private final Pattern hasSpecialChar = Pattern.compile("[^!@#$%^&*]");
if (hasSpecialChar.matcher(password).find()) {
        return "String allows only !@#$%^&* special characters";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code snippet is looking to see if a special character shows up at least once.

A simple correction to this would be to negate the check - i.e look for at least one non-special character which isn't in the set of accepted characters:

```
private final Pattern hasSpecialChar = Pattern.compile("[^!@#$%^&*]");
if (hasSpecialChar.matcher(password).find()) {
    return "String allows only !@#$%^&* special characters";
}
```

Note this answer assumes you only want to allow these special characters, and no other alpha-numeric characters in the output.